# ffmpeg or MP4box how to convert video to universal playable Mpeg-DASH or HLS

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash, mp4box

What is the "good" way to encode (from any format like webm, rtmp) to UNIVERSALLY PLAYABLE hls or dash format ???

I see tons of talks about HLS and MPEG-DASH with video tag that looks like this

```
<video width="90%" height="669" controls > <source src="index.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" > </video>
```

but what is the good command in FFMPEG ?

when I do this

```
ffmpeg -i file.webm  -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -movflags faststart -s 640x360 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls index.m3u8
```

it's playable ONLY in chrome :(

but I need it to be playable in safari, firefox, opera, etc

I recenlty viewed talks about MP4box, what would be the best line to be able to convert any source to a universal playable stream ?

Comment: Showing the **complete** log from your ffmpeg command may show why it is not playing on other browsers.

Comment: @llogan see my answer, I found something

Answer (score 1):

Hi Found a tested AND working code it can be adapted

NOTE 1 ; the input CAN be a https://www.....file.webm ;) the webm can be generated in 1 server and the ffmpeg can be in an other server ;)

NOTE 2 ; (untested) but seems FFMPEG can listen to IP cam as well `ffmpeg -rtsp_flags listen -i rtsp://ownaddress/live.sdp`

FFMPEG :

```
ffmpeg -re -v verbose -i "file.webm" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -crf 18 -profile:v baseline -maxrate 1000k -bufsize 1835k -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags -global_header -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -start_number 1 'index.m3u8'
```

**HLS Universally playable HTML ;)** thanks to hls.js https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
<center><video width="90%" height="600" id="video" controls="" src="https://moctobpltc-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/571329/eight/playlist.m3u" playsinline="true" ></video></center>
<script>
  var video = document.getElementById("video");
  var videoSrc = "https://moctobpltc-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/571329/eight/playlist.m3u8";
  if (video.canPlayType("application/vnd.apple.mpegurl")) {
    video.src = videoSrc;
  } else if (Hls.isSupported()) {
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource(videoSrc);
    hls.attachMedia(video);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

*********** It MUST be inside a http or preferably https: because tested locally is not working

**** AN other note : playsinline="true" in video tag is for IOS and WKWebview to avoid being forced to watch it only in fullscreen

This .m3u8 is a live akamai playlist...